# Where is the tools-reference command in Excel 2010?

Tags: menu, excel-2010

I need to check my file references, but I don't seem to have a "Tools" menu and the "References" command doesn't appear in the list for customizations

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu option I think you are looking for to check file references is not accessed directly from Excel, but is inside the VBA interface.

Go to the Developer Tab and then to "Visual Basic".  In the menu options there, you will find a Tools menu with a References otion which lets you add and remove file references